# Oracle Autonomous Database Date Import

Tags: oracle, date, oracle-autonomous-db

I am trying to load data into an Oracle Autonomous database. I have created a table with a date column using DATE for the column. When I try to import a CSV into the table using the import GUI the data loads but with NULL for all dates.

The date format in the CSV is RRRR-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS. I did check to ensure that when I import the data this format is also specified in the GUI but still all dates are returned NULL in the table.
I tried just importing the data into the database using the GUI without first having created a table. When I do this the table is automatically created and the data loads correctly. But if I were to simply delete the data from the table and try to reload it using the wizard the dates are now all NULL again. I ensured I did specify the format RRRR-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.
If I use an insert statement to insert the date data then I worked as expected and the date are imported into the table.

Comment: Try `'YYYY'` instead of `'RRRR'`.

Comment: I tried both YYYY and RRRR

Comment: I want to help you, but " using the import GUI" = we have more than one! Please show exactly how you are trying to load the data. Also, share your data.